# write(*,...) output to both screen and file

Tags: windows, fortran, stdout, intel-fortran

The program execution may take a long time so I would like to monitor the progress on the screen. And, I want to save the output to a file. In the past I have done this by adding after all write(*,...) statements (a lot) a write(iunit,..) where iunit is some unit number connected to an output file. Surely there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: I'm working on several windows systems including windows xp, which does not seem to have powershell. The subroutine write would be tricky it seems, because of the great variety of forms of write(*,... What about working with the fortran console using AllocConsole or something like that?

Comment: Found something that almost works. Downloaded the GNUwin core utilities, which includes tee. So, invoking myprog.exe in this way: myprog ! tee myprog.out

Comment: The problem comes when I use the start command, which I need to because I'm starting two threads. So start myprog | tee myprog.out produces terminal output but a zero-length file myprog.out

Comment: Found something that works for me. Created `mybat.bat`, which consists of  `myprog | tee myprog.out`, then use `start cmd /c mybat`. I now realize this solution has nothing in particular to do with intel fortran, so it would be nice to be able to edit the main title of this thread :)

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.